# How to show Data label and Legend Combine in SSRS

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2012

I have a Stacked chart generated using SSRS, which has 3 series of data in it like 1. Waiting to Submit 2. External Submission 3. External Approval. I would like to show Data label and Legend Combine in SSRS

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDkwt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the data label, and use `=#VALUE & VBCRLF & #LABEL`

See here for more information on formatting the data points on graphs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-data-points-on-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs